# Running two activities at the same time on the screen

Tags: android, android-activity

I need help doing something that I am sure is simple, but I can't figure out how to do it. I have a counter down and when it gets to the last 60 seconds, it calls a 'lastminute' counter activity. The plan is to overlap the last 60 seconds over the actual application.
Here is the problem, how can I change the code to allow the two activities to start at the same time.
I have tried this;

```
    public void onFinish() {
     startActivity(new Intent ("eu.merso.phoneapp.LASTMINUTE"));
     startActivity(new Intent ("eu.merso.phoneapp.DASHBOARD"));
     onDestroy();
 }
```

but this does not put both applications on the screen, what I want is DASHBOARD on the background and LASTMINUTE on top. LASTMINUTE is alreay a "transparency colour".

Thanks;
Ramón

Comment: You could try using a custom dialog for lastminute

Answer (score 2):

It won't work the way you're currently trying to do it. There can only be one visible activity at a time.

You should first start the dashboard Activity and from there you should start lastminute.

Edit --

Use a Bundle object.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

// Use 0 when the activity is called by the button and 
// 1 when it is called by the timer.
bundle.putInt("event_src", 0);
intentObject.putExtras(bundle);

// In your new activity you can then check whether to display
// the countdown or not
Int eventSrc = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("event_src")
```

Comment: This presents a problem for me. Dashboard can be called from a button or from timer; if called from the button, the 60 second counter (lastminute) shouldn't display.
Calling lastminute from dashboard will only work if I can know who call the activity (button or timer) and can issue and if statement

Comment: I have updated my reply. Should be able to fix it with that code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the lastminute functionality in a dialog that you create and show in the onCreate method of your dashboard activity.

EDIT:
To distinguish between which activity that starts the new activity, use intent extras:

```
//in your calling activity    
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
i.putExtra("from Activity", A.class.getSimpleName());
startActivity(i);   


//in your receiving activity
String from = getIntent().getStringExtra();

if(from.equals(A.class.getSimpleName())){
//do something
}
else if(from.equals(C.class.getSimpleName())){
//do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this presents the problem as the first solution.
Is there a way to know what activity called another activity? If this is possible, then I can create and if..else statement; so when call but the button, the 60 seconds don't show, but when call by the time, then the 60 seconds will show.

Comment: Thanks, I found that solution on another posting on the site and that is more or less what I did and it is working perfect.
When dashboard is called from the button, there is no last minute, but when it is called from the timer, I can see the last 60 seconds.
THANKS for all the HELP.

Comment: @Ramón Díaz - If this answer solves your problem you should accept it by pressing the checkbox next to it, otherwise I encourage you to submit your own solution to your question and accepting that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` in Activity attributes for LastMinute in AndroidManifest.xml. I hope it'll be productive.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but presents the same problem I discussed on answer 1. The LASTMINUTE counter is start every time, I only need it when is called by timer, and not when DASHBOARD is started by the timer.

Answer (score 0):

I think using Android fragments will help u to show two separate activities in the context of another main activity.
try reading this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html